# Ultimate Psionics - Marksman Talents

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Does the Marksman class in the Ultimate Psionics book gain talents?  There is no mention of talents in the class description; however, page 148 lists 0-Level Marksman Powers (Talents).  If the class does gain talents, how many and at what level?

Answer (score 1):

At page 44, it says that *Marksman* gains new powers as indicated on the table (page 46), but begins play knowing no powers (or talents).

Checking the table we see that starting at second level, you learn one power, and that the maximum power level known is *1st*. But there is nothing restricting you from learning a lower level power instead of one from the maximum allowed. So you could pick a talent instead of a 1st level power.

The **Extra Power Known** feat also allows you to start the game with an additional power, including talents if you so desire. And the **Access Psionic Talent** gives your an additional psionic 5 talents, those are gained from any class's list, which means that anyone can pick the marksman's talents if they select this feat.

Comment: there is an extra talent feat too (gives you 5) for more efficiency

Comment: @Duncan From what book is that feat? It didn't make it into the Ultimate Psionics.

Comment: I found the feat: Access Psionic Talent in the Ultimate Psionics page 87.

You are able to manifest minor psionic abilities.
Prerequisite: Manifester level 1st or Unlocked Talent.
Benefit: You gain five talents (see Chapter 5: Powers).  These talents can be from any class list.
Special: This feat may be selected more than once.  Each time, you gain five additional psionic talents.

Comment: Thanks for finding that Jozz, I only own a physical copy of the book, so searching things can take some time. I incorporated that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are four listed mechanisms for implementing Talents as they are *not* an integrated class feature of the Psionic classes, GMs are free to implement all or none of them.

- Automatic Talents, this leaves Marksmen with no free Talents as they only have a 1/3 power progression structure.
- Linked Talents, may or may not give some Marksmen a few free Talents as they pick up Powers Known, the list of Linked Talents is at the bottom right of [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/psionic-talents/) at a glance I spot three or four that may apply.
- Retroactive Talents, only applies to existing characters being given talents in-game when they have an existing Powers Known list.
- Swap With Power Known, allows a Psionic character to forgo a Power Known Slot in exchange for 5 Talents.